# Grouping access to repo GitHub

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have a repo in github with multiple folders like this:

1. **web** : containing the web application
2. **docker** : containing the docker config and other docker stuff.
3. **bash** : containing scripts to run on deploy and others.

And I want to give access to contributors but a web contributor can see and clone only web folder, and docker contributor can see and clone only docker folder... so on.

This is not permission thing (write, read or admin), it more like dividing the project without dividing it really.

Is this something that can be done somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I think a solution is to use git submodule.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Starting-with-Submodules

So you have 3 repositories (web,docker,bash).
On each of the github repositories, you choose the authorized contributors.